# Function "getClient" is never used even when called in MainActivity Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having trouble getting my code to run as a function in my ApiClient is being called in my MainActivity but the intelliJ is saying that the function is never used. I am still fairly new to Kotlin so it may be syntax on my end but I am not completely sure.

Here's my code for the ApiClient

```
class ApiClient {
    val ITUNES_BASE_URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/"
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    fun getClient(): Retrofit? {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ITUNES_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                //                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                //                    .client(client)
                .build()
        }
        return retrofit
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet of the MainActivity where I call getClient

```
  fun displayItunesList() {
        val apiService: ApiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface::class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have other ApiClientclass?
Shoud use ApiClient().getClient() not ApiClient.getClient().
Try add a test fun to your Api Client:

```
class ApiClient {
val ITUNES_BASE_URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/"
private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

fun getClient(): Retrofit? {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ITUNES_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            //                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            //                    .client(client)
            .build()
    }
    return retrofit
}

fun test() {
     ApiClient().getClient()
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
object class ApiClient {
    val ITUNES_BASE_URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/"
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    fun getClient(): Retrofit? {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ITUNES_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    //                    
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    //                    .client(client)
                    .build()
        }
        return retrofit
    }
}
```

and

```
 fun displayItunesList() {
    val apiService: ApiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface::class)
```

Comment: Yea I figured out that I had to change the class to object